# How does event_base_dispatch( ) work?

Tags: c, events, libevent

What happens internally when `event_base_dispatch( )` function is called? Are there any threads that are created which keep running until some signal to stop is received?

Answer (score 4):

`event_base_dispatch()` is a blocking call which executes your defined callbacks inside a loop in the thread that calls the function. It continues to run until there are no more registered events or you call `event_base_loopexit()` / `event_base_loopbreak()`.
See http://www.wangafu.net/~nickm/libevent-book/Ref3_eventloop.html

It is equivalent to `event_base_loop(event_base, 0)`. After taking a quick look at the source code, I don't see any other threads created:
https://github.com/libevent/libevent/blob/master/event.c#L1847